# Wifi disconnects in 1 minute Ubuntu 17.10 (wpa_supplicant)

Tags: ubuntu, networking

The Wifi in my ASUS x552C was working fine at home on the Ubuntu 17.10, but as soon as I came to the university and connected to their Wifi by following some procedures, with the last procedure of having run this file that I downloaded from the university's netstart page.

All the info related to wireless on my laptop: https://pastebin.com/WxezdGiE although the dmesg does not show the logs I have pointed to in this question.

When I turn on the laptop, the wifi works for 1 minute extremely slowly, and then disconnects. Then I have to do the

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

in order to get it working, but the same thing happens over and over again.

Here are the logs that I think are connected to wifi:

> ### ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0
>
> ### nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
>
> ### dbus: Failed to construct signal
>
> ### dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
>
> ### ((src/devices/nm-device.c:1452)): assertion '' failed

I found out that it might be because of the "wpasupplicant 2.4" not accepting weak certificates or something like that.

The output of the dpkg -l network-manager:

```
$ dpkg -l network-manager
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version             Architecture        Description
+++-============================-===================-===================-==============================================================
ii  network-manager              1.8.4-1ubuntu3      amd64               network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
```

The output of the dpkg -l wpasupplicant:

```
~$ dpkg -l wpasupplicant
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version             Architecture        Description
+++-============================-===================-===================-==============================================================
ii  wpasupplicant                2.4-0ubuntu10       amd64               client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

The version of the wpasupplicant shows up as 2.4 even though last night I tried upgrading to 2.6 by downloading the 2.6 .tar file from the internet, and following the instructions for Compilation & Installation from this website. However, I was getting errors while doing that, so I had to search internet for more and more stuff, and eventually when I did the make && make install, it ran without an error, so that made me think that the installation was successful. But, the version still shows up the same in Synaptic and in dpkg.

Any thoughts, leads, information would be EXTREMELY appreciated, because I have not slept normally for 3 days, because the university starts tomorrow and I wanted to have my laptop prepared...

lspci output about network adapters:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

The /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/-=SSID=- file:

```
[connection]
id=-=ID=-
uuid=-=UUID=-
type=wifi
autoconnect-priority=20
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=-=SSID=-

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=-=myAcc@Xxx.Xxx.Xxx=-
password=-=myPassword=-
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

The source of the file (SecureW2_JoinNow.run) that I downloaded from the University's page in order to get the wifi set up is:

```
#!/bin/sh

die () {
    [ ! -z "$1" ] && echo "Fatal: $1"
    [ ! -z "$tmpdir" -a -d "$tmpdir" ] && ${RM} -Rf "$tmpdir"
    exit 1
}

missing () {
    echo 'Executable `'$1'` seems to be missing, not executable or cannot be located with `which`.'
    echo ''
    echo 'Please install this program using your distribution-specific package manager (e.g. `apt-get` or `yum`).'
    echo 'If this does not solve the issue, you can try editing this script by hand to provide the proper'
    echo 'executable locations, or request your network administrator to contact SecureW2 Support.'
    die
}

findutil () {
    for u in "$@"; do \
        p="$("${WHICH}" "$u" 2> /dev/null)"
        [ ! -z "$p" ] && break
    done
    [ -z "$p" ] && missing "$1"
    return 0
}

which --skip-alias which > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
    WHICH="$(which --skip-alias which)"
else
    WHICH="$(which which)"
fi

[ ! -x "${WHICH}" ] && missing which

findutil mkdir      && MKDIR="$p"
findutil rm         && RM="$p"
findutil tar        && TAR="$p"
findutil gzip       && GZIP="$p"
findutil pwd        && PWD="$p"
findutil sed        && SED="$p"
findutil readlink   && READLINK="$p"
findutil python \
         python2 \
         python3    && PYTHON="$p"

tmpdir="/tmp/securew2-joinnow-$$.tmp"
archive="$(${READLINK} -f "$0")"

${MKDIR} -p "$tmpdir" || die "Error creating temporary directory $tmpdir"
cd $tmpdir || die "Error switching working directory to $tmpdir"
${SED} '0,/^#ARCHIVE#$/d' "$archive" | ${GZIP} -d | ${TAR} x || die "Error extracting embedded archive"
${PYTHON} main.py "$@"
retval=$?
${RM} -Rf "$tmpdir"
exit $retval

#ARCHIVE#
And tons of numbers and symbols...
```

Comment: Please add your wpasupplicant.conf file. 802.1X? EDUROAM?  It may make more sense going to the Uni helpdesk services than asking here.

Comment: The thing is that the wpasupplicant did not create the .conf file on its own in /etc/wpa_supplicant/. I have created it manually afterwards, so I don't think it will be helpful to add it here... It is 802.11. I did go to the Uni helpdesk but they told me they could not help... They are not of a really great help. I am adding the whole information regarding the wireless on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your problem is this bug: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10120081/

I've the wifi stack on a router running Openwrt, and if you put traffic on it, it happens and the wifi is unusable.

So your solution is to wait until that bug get fixed!